# Add boxplots to grouped stacked bar chart in D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to add [box plots](http://bl.ocks.org/jensgrubert/7789216) on top of each stacked bar. I have used [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/gencay/4629518) to create groups of stacked bars and now each state needs to have 4 box plots (one for every stacked bar). I have a screenshot of exactly what I need but no permissions to post it

I have a JSON array that contains all information needed like Q1, Q3, median, min and max values for the whiskers.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks,
Alexis

Comment: What are the box plot values based on?  A third variable separate from the counts used in the bar chart?  What scale would be used for them, and how would it match up with the stacked bar chart scale?  If you can post some sample data (and create your own rough sketch of what you want to achieve), that would help suggest where to start.

Comment: @AmeliaBR  Sample data: http://postimg.org/image/uy1klcumb/  Sketch: http://postimg.org/image/djlh7g5xf/  Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks

Comment: You should show what you've tried and what problems/errors you are incurring in. At the moment it seems like you are asking us to do the work.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the box plots and barcharts are completely independent except for a common x-axis.  Draw your bar chart, then increase the padding on the x-scale's range bands, and draw your boxplot.